# Solving inexact DE with multivariable integrating factor provided.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just spent more time than I care to admit pushing through the algebra of this question and, although I arrived at the answer, **I'm curious to know if there is some simplification that could be done earlier on that would reduce the amount of algebra involved or otherwise improve the method** (without introducing entirely new concepts; i.e. sticking to the general framework used here)?

**The question:** "Find a 1-parameter family of solutions of the differential equation $3xy + y^2 + (x^2+xy)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ using the integrating factor $\mu(x,y) = \frac{1}{xy(2x+y)}$"

**The work:**

Multiply in the integrating factor:

$\frac{3xy + y^2}{xy(2x+y)} + \frac{x^2+xy}{xy(2x+y)}\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

Normally, I would expect some nice simplification in one of the expressions, but I could not find anything substantial (at least not for both terms) and so after simplifying the first term a bit:

$\frac{3xy + y^2}{xy(2x+y)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x+y}$

I integrated w.r.t. $x$ to obtain:

$\int \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x+y} \,dx = \ln x + \frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+y) + k(y)$

Differentiating this expression w.r.t. $y$ should yield an expression equivalent to the coefficient on $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the first line, above, i.e.:

$\frac{d}{dy}\big(\ln x + \ln(2x+y) + k(y)\big) = \frac{1}{2(2x+y)} + k'(y) = \frac{x+y}{y(2x+y)}$

Isolating for $k'(y)$:

$k'(y) = \frac{x+y}{y(2x+y)} - \frac{1}{2(2x+y)} = \frac{1}{2y}$

therefore $k(y) = \frac{1}{2}\ln y + C$ and an implicit solution is given by $\phi(x,y) = \ln x + \frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+y) + \frac{1}{2}\ln y = c$.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated - usually by the end of such a question I would have an idea of how to construct similar questions, but in this case I do not understand where the complexity is coming from / how it is being created (or from whence it arises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems right in itself (although I believe there's a minor mistake). I think the easiest way to see this is to write both terms in partial fractions:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac 1x + \frac{1}{2x + y}\right)dx +
\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{2x + y}\right)dy & = 0.
\end{align}
It is easy that this equation is exact.
You can now move things around, like this:
\begin{align}
\frac 12\left(2\frac{dx}x + \frac{dy}y + \frac{d(2x + y)}{2x + y}\right) & = 0.
\end{align}
This can now be integrated term by term, yielding
$$
2 \log x + \log y + \log(2x + y) = C.
$$

Comment: The partial fractions move was what I was missing. I had never seen it applied to a multivariable context. I'm interested to see how it would apply to higher-order factors in more than one variable. If you happen to know a good source on the topic, I'd be very interested. Thank you kindly for your time and excellent answer!